# Octave - Figure window hangs on trying to save figure

Tags: octave

I am trying to save an ellipsoid drawn using Octave. Unfortunately, the figure window hangs upon trying to save the figure. Following is the code:

```
AR = 2.5;
nseg = 200;
[X, Y, Z] = ellipsoid(0,0,0,AR/2,0.5,0.5, nseg);
hf = figure();
shading interp;
surf(X,Y,Z, 'edgecolor','none','facecolor',[.8 .8 .8]);
axis equal;
%plotcube([AR 1 1],[-AR/2 -0.5 -0.5],.8,[1 0 0]); 
light('Position', [1 1 1]);
view([1, 1., 1]);

set(gca,'visible','off');
print (hf, "figure1.eps")
```

I tried different `graphics_toolkit` options such as `qt`, `fltk`, and `gnuplot`. The `gnuplot` option does not render properly since I believe it supports only 2D objects. However, the `qt` and `fltk` renders the object properly but I could not save the figure.

Comment: Try `print (hf, "-deps", "figure1.eps")`. Otherwise it’ll try to print to a printer.

Comment: What Cris said, and also, alternatively, you could use the `saveas` function instead, which allows you to save a figure to a particular format, as autodetected by the filename's extension (so, e.g. `saveas(hf, 'filename.eps')`)

Comment: I tried both these methods and as well more other options. Nothing works yet.

Comment: When you decrease `nseg` it works fine. It starts to hang longer and longer with increasing number of segments. Not a solution but I just want to let you know in case you don't need all the detail.

Comment: @Cem: Thanks. It works as you suggested! Apparently I had to wait longer with `nseg=200`. If you would like, you can post the comment as an answer.